# How to use CanContentRenderOutsideBounds on ListView

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to use `CanContentRenderOutsideBounds` on ListView. I know we can use it on ScrollViewer and that works, but it doesn't work on ListView. I've tried this:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentRenderOutsideBounds="True">
   <ListViewItem>
     <Textblock>Content</Textblock>
   </ListViewItem>
   <!--This will be a lot of items-->
</ListView>
```

So, can we use `CanContentRenderOutsideBounds` for ListView? If don't, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ListView, it uses the default style, as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">       
     ………      
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
            TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
            HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
           …...>
                       <ItemsPresenter Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
             …… />
                   </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, ListView has the built-in `ScrollViewer`, so you could use [Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree)  to find this ScrollViewer, then set its `CanContentRenderOutsideBounds` property to true in the `Loaded` event of ListView. Please refer to the following code.

Xaml code:

```
<ListView Height="100" x:Name="myListView" Loaded="ListView_Loaded">
    <ListViewItem>
       <TextBlock Text="item1"/>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>
       <TextBlock Text="item2"/>
    </ListViewItem>
     // a lot of items
 </ListView>
```

Code behind：

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var sc = FindChild<ScrollViewer>(myListView);
            sc.CanContentRenderOutsideBounds = true;
        }

public T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                if (child is T typedChild)
                {                   
                        return typedChild;                   
                }
                var inner = FindChild<T>(child);
                if (inner != null)
                {
                    return inner;
                }
            }
            return default;
        }
```